# How do I include background images url in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image]

This is my wordpress plugin code. How to dynamic background-image URL in a WordPress plugin?

```
<?php 
function active_qploader() {?>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #preloader { 
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow:visible;
        background-color:#333;
        background-image:url("images/test.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-attachment:center center;
        background-position:center;
     }
    </style>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one, you need not mention there echo, just give please:

```
<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/test.png', FILE ) ; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use semi-relative path or full path.

**Semi:**

```
#preloader {
    background-image: url( '/wp-content/plugins/pluginName/images/test.png' );
}
```

**Full Path:**

```
#preloader {
    background-image: url( 'http://yourWebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginName/images/test.png' );
}
```

For **Dynamic Background** you have to use this hook:

```
function dynamicPicture() {
    global $post;
    $backgroundImage = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'background', true );
    if( $backgroundImage ) :
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        #preloader { background-image: url(<?php echo $backgroundImage;?>); }
        </style>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_print_plugin_style', 'dynamicPicture' );
```

**Edit:**

```
<?php
'<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/test.png', __FILE__ ) . '" > ';
?>
```

For further [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url).

Comment: I didn't need static image url or dynamic background . i need just dynamic url under wordpress plugin images folder.

Comment: yes dynamic plugin URL but this url under css  background-image:url();   not img tag

Comment: Same thing applies on background image as well. You just copy that style and paste into PHP page and apply that plugin URL.

Comment: Never hard-code `wp-content/` into a URL, that folder structure is not certain, it is changeable with `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME` constants in `wp-config.php`